# Quotient of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ by $(x-a)^2$ or by $x^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Are $\mathbb{C}[x]/((x-a)^2)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^2)$ isomorphic? I see that the elements (cosets) of each rings can be identified with linear polynomials $c_1 x + c_0$, but I am not sure what to make of the operations. I thought the natural isomorphism between them would be defined by $[1+((x-a)^2)] \mapsto [1+(x^2)]$ and $[x+((x-a)^2)] \mapsto [x+(x^2)]$, but in the first ring, $$[x+((x-a)^2)]^2 = [x^2+((x-a)^2)] = [2ax-a^2 + ((x-a)^2)]$$ while in the second ring, $$[x+(x^2)]^2 = [0+(x^2)].$$

Comment: They are isomorphic, but not, as you point out, via $[x+((x-a)^2)] \mapsto [x+(x^2)]$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Oh I see... it should be $[x-a + ((x-a)^2)] \mapsto [x+(x^2)]$. Thanks!

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Is there a way to show that the two rings are isomorphic that is quicker or more elegant than showing that this map is a homomorphism, injective, and surjective?

Comment: I think of it as the isomorphism of quotient rings induced by the change-of-variables isomorphism on $\mathbb C[x]$ given by $x \mapsto x+a$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Okay, I have done so.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the isomorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras $$\Phi: \mathbb C[x] \to \mathbb C[x]$$ given by $$x \mapsto x-a.$$ We compose this with the canonical projection map $\pi: \mathbb C[x] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb C[x]/((x-a)^2)$. Observe that $\ker(\pi\Phi) = (x^2)$, so by the first isomorphism theorem, we get the desired isomorphism $$\widehat{\pi\Phi}: \mathbb C[x]/(x^2) \overset{\sim}{\to} \mathbb C[x]/((x-a)^2).$$

More explicitly, this isomorphism is given by $$1+(x^2) \mapsto 1+((x-a)^2)$$ and $$x+(x^2) \mapsto x-a+((x-a)^2).$$